# Grouping data points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am a beginner with QGIS.  What I need to do is take a group of zipcodes and group them together (create a territory) in a way that is recorded in an underlying database.

Ideally, I would like to highlight a group of zipcodes and assign a value to them as an attribute (column) in the underlying layer file (database).

Anyone know if that can be done in the mapping software?

Comment: welcome to stackexchange! yes, that seems possible if i understand it correctly. what kind of data do you have? Depending on that you can go different ways to get your result

Comment: It is aggregated Insurance revenue/loss data at a zip code level.  I am just trying to create larger territories by grouping zip codes with similar revenue and loss characteristics together.

Answer (score 1):

Select features you want to group. Right click your zip code feature class in the Layers Panel. Open Attribute Table. Click on the pencil icon in the top left corner to start an edit mode. Click the field calculator (last icon on right) and "Click update existing field" if you have one to store the grouping values or choose to "create a new field" if you don't. Type in value for grouping in the expression box, make sure Only update # selected features is checked. Continue this process until all the polygons have their group values. Stop and save edits. Close attribute table.

Go to Vector menu at top of screen->Geoprocessing Tools->Dissolve. Choose the feature class you just edited as the input and select the field you based your grouping on for the Dissolve field. That should do it.